# java.lang.NullPointerException - AutoCompleteTextView - HoneyComb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, autocompletetextview

I am getting a weird issue when using AutoCompleteTextView component on a device running on Honeycomb (Android 3.0) (using Motorola Xoom to test). I get a Nullpointer exception with the following stacktrace :

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.widget.PopupWindow.getMaxAvailableHeight(PopupWindow.java:1152)
>   at
>   android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1054)
>   at
>   android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:516)
>   at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1047)
>   at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:931)
>   at
>   android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:914)
>   at
>   android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
>   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
>   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
>   at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)

Note that I do not get this exception on any other versions of Android including Gingerbread. Its really hard to debug since I do not have the original source code of Honeycomb code base. I would appreciate if anyone can help me out.

Thanks,
Torri.

Comment: Can we see the code for how you are using getMaxAvailableHeight?

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact exception. Everything works in 2.*, but in 3.x there all thrown this exception, and simply try catch didn't work.

Finally I found that, if I remove the below line from the view, then it worked for me:

```
android:dropDownAnchor="@+id/searchField"
```

Comment: almost the same problem so this helped me realize it.  I had the wrong name in this field due to copy/paste mistake.

Comment: THANK YOU. This was my problem! I had renamed the ID of the referenced view and not updated it below.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can help but I had a similarly weird problem with a button. It worked fine on all versions except 3.0
So I did this:

```
try{
  mButton.setOnClickListener(...
     //code...

}catch(NullPointerException e){

}
```

After this no more errors and guess what? The button works fine now on 3.0 !

Comment: You should really report that issue on the Android bug tracker!